# Why are my Keen IO counts off by one day?

Tags: analytics, keen-io

Using the daily interval on Keen IO, my counts are off by one day as compared to what I see if I just look at the counts for a single day. Why are they different? I'm running this query in the Keen IO Explorer.

For example my query is

```
count 'subscriptions'
timeframe 'last_7_days'
interval 'daily'
```

The line chart shows a count of 87 for 06/06/2017.

Then I run this count for a single day:

```
count 'subscriptions'
timeframe start '2017-06-06T:00:00.000Z'
timeframe end '2017-06-07T00:00:00.000Z'
```

An the count shows the value for 06/05/2017.
Why are they different?

Answer (score 3):

This is related to the browser's timeframe/timezone presentation of the data. Change the `timezone` parameter of the query to match the timezone of your browser and you should see that the date labels on your line chart behave like you would expect.

The line chart uses the browser's timezone to decide how to delineate the days and draw the chart, whereas the single count simply displays the result back from the API. That's how it can appear that you're getting "different results" for the same day.

Troubleshooting tip for the future: you can inspect the raw JSON of the query result to see what is coming back from the API.

Here's what the query result looks like for a count with a 7 day interval. You can see the exact datetime and timezone used in the query.

```js
{
  "result": [
    {
      "value": 70,
      "timeframe": {
        "start": "2017-05-31T07:00:00.000Z",
        "end": "2017-06-01T07:00:00.000Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "value": 106,
      "timeframe": {
        "start": "2017-06-01T07:00:00.000Z",
        "end": "2017-06-02T07:00:00.000Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "value": 141,
      "timeframe": {
        "start": "2017-06-02T07:00:00.000Z",
        "end": "2017-06-03T07:00:00.000Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "value": 63,
      "timeframe": {
        "start": "2017-06-03T07:00:00.000Z",
        "end": "2017-06-04T07:00:00.000Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "value": 55,
      "timeframe": {
        "start": "2017-06-04T07:00:00.000Z",
        "end": "2017-06-05T07:00:00.000Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "value": 64,
      "timeframe": {
        "start": "2017-06-05T07:00:00.000Z",
        "end": "2017-06-06T07:00:00.000Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "value": 50,
      "timeframe": {
        "start": "2017-06-06T07:00:00.000Z",
        "end": "2017-06-07T07:00:00.000Z"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

You can also use the "Embed" button in the explorer to see the exact code used in compiling your query.

e.g.

```
  var query = new Keen.Query("count", {
    event_collection: "create_organization",
    interval: "daily",
    timeframe: "this_7_days",
    timezone: "US/Pacific"
  });
```